# 404 Not Found when access Laravel storage files in subfolder directly on browser

Tags: laravel, laravel-filesystem

I'm using Laravel 9 with NGINX as the web server. I've running storage link command so I can access the storage files, but when I'm trying to access file which is placed inside subdirectory/subfolder in storage folder, I got 404. Any solution for this?

**Subfolder File**
[image]

**File directly in Storage**
[image]

**My Storage Folder Structure**

[image]

Fyi, I'm accessing it on React App and store the file from API.

Comment: seeing your folder and file structure isn't that correct behavior? the file you are trying to access doesn't exist in that folder or are you testing by moving the files to the folder back and forth to test? You are accessing the file that is not in the folder.

Comment: Ah, I'm sorry for the image. I actually just trying to move the file before I take the picture. Then I moved back to the subdirectory.

Comment: I just edited the image. Make it clear.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found the solution. Solved by changing the folder access permissions to 755.

```
chmod 755 answer_attachments/
```

Comment: Make mistakes, found the solution, share it with other people.  #Upvoted

Comment: Haha. Fortunately found the solution. Thanks.